# Excel Condition missplacing

Tags: excel

I am trying to make an average of multiple cells, and I want to ignore to zero cells.

Here is my formula `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(L4:L10;L12:L18;L20:L26;L28:L34;L36:L37);"")` and I don't know where to put the condition to ignore zero `"<>0"` . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can't use `AVERAGEIF` with multiple average ranges. There is only one average range possible. The question is why shall `L11`, `L19`, `L27` and `L35` be excluded?

Comment: @barryhoudini it wouldn't be the same if `L11`,`L19`, etc, had numbers in them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only have positive values and zeroes you can average without zeroes, for non-contiguous ranges using this syntax

`=IFERROR(SUM(L4:L10;L12:L18;L20:L26;L28:L34;L36:L37)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((L4:L10;L12:L18;L20:L26;L28:L34;L36:L37);0);2);"")`

The `FREQUENCY` part gives you a two element array, one being the count of zeroes, the other the count of positive values, `INDEX` then retrieves the second of those (the number of positive values), so if you divide the sum by that count you get the average excluding zeroes. `FREQUENCY` function (unlike `AVERAGEIF`) accepts a non contiguous range argument (a "union")

....but if you can identify which rows to exclude by using values in another column then it's easier with `AVERAGEIFS`, e.g. if on the excluded rows, e.g. in `K11`, `K21`, `K35` etc. they all have the value "Total" you can use this version:

`=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(L4:L37;L4:L37;"<>0";K4:K37;"<>Total");"")`

adjust depending on the exact text, wildcards are possible

Comment: Regarding `K4:K37;"<>Total"` bit, text wouldn't matter to include within `average()`. So there is no need to filter them.

Comment: I'm assuming that the cells in column L - L11, L19 etc. contain numbers (in fact the OP says they do) but that the text, e.g. "totals" will be in another column (I chose K), so it does need that condition for my assumed scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`.

Example data:

```
Values
1
-3
0
5
777
3
0
0
8
text
4
5
6
0
6
7
```

Formulas:

```
B18=SUMIF(A2:A17,"<>0",A2:A17)-SUM(A6,A11,A15)
B19=COUNTIF(A2:A5,"<>0")+COUNTIF(A7:A10,"<>0")+COUNTIF(A12:A17,"<>0")
B20=B18/B19
```

[image]